# Create an HTML anchor link to pre select an option from dropdown menu

Tags: html, hyperlink, dropdown

I would like to have a link which preselects an option from a dropdown menu. all located on the same website.

is this possible?

thanks

Comment: can clarify your question more? you want to have a preselects an option? you can simply use a little css code. which type of dropdown you have? do you use any ui framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "selected="selected" as attribute to make option pre select.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes thanks, but how to link this to an HTML Anchor? Any idea?